# accessing bash arguments and commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

There is plenty of info out ther about accessing `-a` type arguments
But I want to create a script with usage like so, Actually I have already writin the help text

```
usage: pubkeys command options

This script mannages your public keys.

Commands:
        add - Add public key(s) to your authorized_keys file
        get - Echo public key(s)
        remove - Remove public key(s) from your authorized_keys file

OPTIONS:
   -h   Show this help message
   -u   specify user, default is current user
   -v   Display Version and exit
```

How can I access the "Command" and only then parse the options?

Comment: Can you specify, how are you currently accessing "-a"? There are multiple ways. If you are using $1, $2 etc, you can use it for string commands the same way.

Comment: currently i'm using `getopts`

Comment: @dj_boy simply inspect the value of ${1} before doing parsing with getopts?

Comment: In this example, with fixed position, I agree with @PatrickTrentin